# How to propagate exceptions out of a private flow?

Tags: mule

I read somewhere that exceptions are not propagated out of private flows in Mule (3.2). If so, is there another mule construct that:

- is a chain of message processors
- can be referenced from another construct
- propagates exceptions to the calling construct

?

Or, is there a way to circumvent the restriction that exceptions are not propagated out of private flows?

You could use the mule-config.xml and the java code below to reproduce the behavior I am describing above in which exceptions do not propagate out of private flows:

**mule-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
  xmlns:stdio="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio/3.2/mule-stdio.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.2/mule.xsd">

<stdio:connector name="unused" promptMessage="Yes? " messageDelayTime="1000" />

<flow name="throwsException">
    <component class="apackage.ThrowsException" />
</flow>

<flow name="echo">
    <stdio:inbound-endpoint system="IN"/>

    <flow-ref name="throwsException" />
    <component class="apackage.DuplicateString" />

    <stdio:outbound-endpoint system="OUT"/>
</flow>

</mule>
```

**ThrowsException.java**

```
package apackage;

public class ThrowsException {

    public String throwsException(String string) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}
```

**DuplicateString.java**

```
package apackage;

public class DuplicateString {

    public String duplicateString(String string) {
        return string.concat(string);
    }

}
```

Comment: Very surprised by this question: have you experienced first hand exceptions being swallowed in sub-flows?

Comment: added code to the original question to make it easy to duplicate the behavior I am describing.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your config, it's indeed very helpful for reproducing the behavior you're noticing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to use a sub-flow rather than another flow.

- A flow, has it's own lifecycle, exception handling and processing strategy etc.
- A sub-flow acts exactly like a macro that can be reused, it's identical to copying and pasting the same processors into the flow that is referencing and using the sub-flow.

HTH.

Comment: OMG Daniel, you have eagle eyes! I was certain beluchin had used a sub-flow and didn't notice he used a flow element as if it was a sub-flow! Excellent catch!

Comment: could you point us to documentation describing the semantics of sub-flow? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dan is right.

Exception propagation was not possible but since Mule 3.3 you will be able to propagate exceptions thrown in private flow so the caller flow exception strategy can manage it.

Comment: But when will you use a private flow as opposed to a sub-flow? If you need to manually propagate exceptions, why not using a sub-flow? I guess I don't understand the use case for private flows...